# Why does the DSL show "Couldn't resolve reference to "?

Tags: grammar, xtext

I am implementing a grammar with three sections. In the first section I declare components with their interfaces, for instance Component A with interfaces interface_1, interface_2. In the third section I declare some restrictions, for instance component A can acces component B through interface XXXX. When I try to cross-reference the interfaces of a component I get the error "Couldn't resolve reference to ProbeInterface 'interface_1'"?.

I tried several examples from internet but none of them works to my case.

This is part of my grammar:

```
ArchitectureDefinition:
    'Abstractions' '{' abstractions += DSLAbstraction+ '}'  
    'Compositions' '{' compositions += DSLComposition* '}'  
    'Restrictions' '{' restrictions += DSLRestriction* '}'  
;


DSLComposition:

   DSLProbe|DSLSensor

;


DSLRestriction:

'sensor' t=[DSLSensor] 'must-access-probe' type = [DSLProbe] 'through-interface' probeinterface=[ProbeInterface] ';'

;

DSLSensor: 

  'Sensor' name=ID ';'
;



DSLProbe:

'Probe' name=ID  ('with-interface' probeinterface=ProbeInterface)? ';'

;  


ProbeInterface :

    name+=ID (',' name+=ID)* 
;
```

And the implementation:

```
Abstractions
{

   Sensor sensor_1 ;
   Probe probe_1 with-interface interface_1, interface_2;
}

Compositions{}

Restrictions
{
   sensor sensor_1 must-access-probe probe_1 through-interface 
   interface_1;
}
```

I expect that interface_1 or interface_2 can be referenced by the grammar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the grammar you posted is incomplete

the way you define the interfaces is really bad.
default naming works only with single valued name attributes

```
ProbeInterface :

    name+=ID (',' name+=ID)* 
;
```

better

```
DSLProbe:

'Probe' name=ID  ('with-interface' probeinterfaces+=ProbeInterface ("," probeinterfaces+=ProbeInterface)*)? ';'

;  


ProbeInterface :

    name=ID
;
```

it looks like the qualified name of a Interface is

```
<probename>.<interfacename>
```

- you either have to adapt the name provider
- or the grammar and model to use qualiedname `ref=[Thing|FQN]` with `FQN: ID ("." ID)*;`
- or you implement scoping properly which is what you want to do likely in your case since you want to restrict the inferfaces for specific probes

here is a sample

```
    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference === MyDslPackage.Literals.DSL_RESTRICTION__PROBEINTERFACE) {
            if (context instanceof DSLRestriction) {
                val probe = context.type
                return Scopes.scopeFor(probe.probeinterfaces)
            }
        }
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }
```

Comment: I tried the last solution (scope method) and just changed the line `val probe` with `val probe = context.type as DSLProbe`. However the problem still persist. I printed probe.probeinterfaces and get `[sasDsl.impl.ProbeInterfaceImpl@40b1ca68 (name: [interface_1]), sasDsl.impl.ProbeInterfaceImpl@3d630aef (name: [interface_2])]`  but in the implementation they don't appears. What could it be?

Comment: please provide your complete grammar, unit test and scope provider in your question

Comment: (there is no "implementation" concept in your grammar)

Comment: and of course if there is a implementation my if else would not catch it

Comment: Finally I resolved. Change `ProbeInterface : name+=ID ;`  by `ProbeInterface : name=ID ;`

Comment: arg i thought i had edited that in my grammar but seems like stackoverflow did not store that